# How to display different page layouts for classic and lightning users?

Tags: apex, lightning

I have a Lightning Component embedded in a inline VF page which works well in both classic and lightning. I want to be able to display  lightning component directly without embedding it in VF page to lightning users Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can [expose the component to Lightning Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm), then you'll be able to add it to pages in Lightning Experience using Lightning App Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean, but you can create something called a Lightning Tab:

[Add Lightning Components as Custom Tabs in Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_lex.htm)

You need your component (or a wrapper component) to implement "force:appHostable":

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
```

And then do the following:

> 1. Create a custom tab for this component.
>
>    a.   From Setup, enter Tabs in the Quick Find box, then select Tabs.
>
>    b.   Click New in the Lightning Component Tabs related list.
>
>    c.   Select the Lightning component that you want to make available to users.
>
>    d.   Enter a label to display on the tab.
>
>    e.   Select the tab style and click Next.
>
>    f.   When prompted to add the tab to profiles, accept the default and click Save.
> 2. Add your Lightning components to the App Launcher.
>
>    a.   From Setup, enter Apps in the Quick Find box, then select Apps.
>
>    b.   Click New. Select Custom app and then click Next.
>
>    c.   Enter Lightning for App Labeland click Next.
>
>    d.   In the Available Tabs dropdown menu, select the Lightning Component tab you created and click the right arrow button to add it to the custom app.
>
>    e.   Click Next. Select the Visible checkbox to assign the app to profiles and then Save.
> 3. Check your output by navigating to the App Launcher in Lightning Experience. Your custom app should appear in theApp Launcher. Click the custom app to see the components you added.